# How to remove field from cell / row properties dialog in TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-5

I need to remove some cell/row properties field like Scope, H Align & V Align. Any way to remove this field.

Cell Properties:
[image]

Row Properties:
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `table` plugin's documentation can be found here:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/table/

There is not a way to hide these specific fields via configuration so your best solution would be to copy the table plugin and modify the code that displays these dialogs to hide the elements you don't want shown.

Answer (score 0):

As a hack, you could simply add a "`display:none!important`" style targetting the elements you want to have hidden in the dialogs.

I advise against removing them from the DOM, as the tinyMCE plugin *could* be targeting them, thus generating javascript errors in the console, and possibly breaking things. Hiding them is a much safer hack.